# Horizontal Scrolling UICollectionView with Two rows and dynamic width, cell not align to the left

Tags: swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I've horizontal scrollable collectionView having two rows with dynamic width. The issue is the cell is not align to the left, it always stays in the centre.

```
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
    var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0

    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
            leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        }

        layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

        leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
        maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
    }

    return attributes
}
```

}

I am using this code for alignment but If I use this custom layout the horizontal scrolling does not work, it work as vertical scrolling

using this code there is screenshot, now it's working as vertical but I want horizontal
[image]

if I set the layout to the horizontal here is output

```
scrollingDirection = .horizontal
```

[image: horizontal scrolling cell alignment]

Here is collectionView code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let text = userInterests[indexPath.item].title ?? ""
    let width = width(of: text)
    let widthWithPadding = width + CellFrame.textPadding
    return CGSize(width: widthWithPadding, height: CellFrame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { CellFrame.padding }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { CellFrame.padding }
```

I want to achieve Horizontal Scrolling + Two Rows + Cell left Align
only left align cell problem is left.
any code snippet or guide will be appreciated.

Comment: you can use two sections with horizontal scrolling

Comment: If I use two sections how the problem will be solved ?@AzharTahir

Comment: actually I mean collection view embed in table view, where table view will have two cell(row) and each cell will have collection view with horizontal scroll, hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: @AzharTahir but they will scroll individually instead of both at the same time ?, but still issue it If we have dynamic width than cell goes to the centre, this is the issue

Comment: you can use scroll delegate for both two scroll

Answer (score 0):

#### Left Aligned `UICollectionView` with two rows and dynamic with

##### Horizontal scrolling

Here is the code for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. You just need to assign it to the your collection view layout.

[image]

***Note:*** Provide the Table cell height to double of collection cell height in order to get two rows.

```
class LeftAlignedHorizontalCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

required override init() {super.init(); common()}
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder); common()}
    
    private func common() {
        scrollDirection = .horizontal
        estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        minimumLineSpacing = 10
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(
                    in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        
        guard let att = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in:rect) else {return []}
        
        let group = att.group(by: {$0.frame.origin.y})
        
        var x: CGFloat = sectionInset.left
        
        for attr in group {
            x = sectionInset.left
            for a in attr.value {
                if a.representedElementCategory != .cell { continue }
                a.frame.origin.x = x
                x += a.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            }
        }
        return att
   }}


extension Array {
func group<T: Hashable>(by key: (_ element: Element) -> T) -> [[Element]] {
    var categories: [T: [Element]] = [:]
    var groups = [[Element]]()
    for element in self {
        let key = key(element)
        if case nil = categories[key]?.append(element) {
            categories[key] = [element]
        }
    }
    categories.keys.forEach { key in
        if let group = categories[key] {
            groups.append(group)
        }
    }
    return groups
}}
```